# Solve functional equation: $f(x) + f(y) = f\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right) $

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, logarithms

The equation being : $$ f(x) + f(y) = f\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right) $$
The most obvious answer is, $$f(x) = C\arctan x$$
but there is another possible answer e.i
$$ f(x) =  \log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) $$ which i am unable to get by the process i have provided. First substituting: $$    x = y = 0 \Rightarrow f(0) = 0$$
then partially differentiating the original equation wrt to $x$ and then $y$ individually (provided $x \ne y$), we'll get : $$ f'(x) = f'\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)\frac{1+y^2}{(1-xy)^2}   - (i)$$
$$ f'(y) = f'\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)\frac{1+x^2}{(1-xy)^2}   - (ii)$$
diving equations $i$ by $ii$ we get
$$  \frac{f'(x)}{f'(y)} = \frac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}$$
$$ \Rightarrow f'(x)\left(1+x^2\right) = f'(y)\left(1+y^2\right)$$
which is only possible if the above equation is equal to some constant $c$, since $x \neq y$
$$    f'(x)\left(1+x^2\right) = C $$
$$ \Rightarrow f'(x) = \frac{C}{1+x^2} $$
$$ \Rightarrow f(x) = \int \frac{C}{1+x^2} = C \arctan x + K $$
since $f(0) = 0, k = 0$
$$ \therefore  f(x) = C \arctan x $$

Also, when do i know that there is no more functions that satisfy the original equation ?

Comment: Are you sure that $f(x) = \log (1-x)/(1+x)$ works? I checked the algebra, and I don't think it does. $\quad$ As a quick first check, the denominator on the LHS is $ (1+x)(1+y)$, while the denominator on the RHS is $(1-xy) + (x+y)$. These are nowhere close to each other, so it's unlikely to cancel out easily.

Comment: @CalvinLin, I checked as well, and it works, at least if $c=1$.

Comment: @Doug [This is what I get in wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281-x%29%2F%281%2Bx%29+*+%281-y%29%2F%281%2By%29++-+%28+1+-+%28x%2By%29%2F%281-xy%29+%29+%2F+%28+1+%2B+%28x%2By%29+%2F+%281-xy%29+%29).  We need $xy(x+y) = 0 $ for equality to hold. $\quad$ Alternatively, we can show that $f(0.5) + f(0.5) \neq f(4/3)$, because the LHS is defined, but the RHS is not defined.

Comment: @CalvinLin, yes, I had an incorrect minus sign attached to the $xy$.

Comment: So, I suppose that means that if $x$ and $y$ are imaginary, it should work, i.e. $\ln((1-ix)/(1+ix))$, which is essentially another way of expressing arctangent.

Comment: As for the original equation, I think it seems quite promising to substitute $x=\tan\alpha$ and $y=\tan\beta$ and then use the formula for the tangent of sum (surely, this is motivated by the hypothetical answer).

Comment: This is not functional analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to say that there is only one differentiable solution (which you found) based on the uniqueness theorems for ODEs.

You can also check that $f$ is odd to conclude that the logarithm cannot be a solution.

As far as non-smooth solutions, I'm not sure there is any general way to decide if there are any.  But perhaps someone else knows more about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing $x=0$ and $y=0$ gives
$f(0)+f(0)=f(0) \implies f(0)=0$.

Let $z$ be any real number other than $0$.
$1/z$ is defined since $z \ne 0$.

Substituting $z$ and $1/z$ into the functional equation we get:

$\large f(z) + f(1/z) = f\left(\frac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{0}\right)$

$\large f(z) = f\left(\frac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{0}\right) - f(1/z)$

but the right hand side is undefined because of the division by $0$.

So $f(z)$ is undefined.

In summary, $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$ but otherwise it is undefined.

Comment: The solution is arctangent.  There is no issue with letting $f(\pm a/0) = f(\pm \infty) = \pm \pi/2, \quad a \ne 0$.